# Is it possible to deploy same aws lambda jar in multiple regions at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a deployed a lambda in US EAST region. There is a need to deploy the same lambda in multiple regions. Is there a simple way(in the portal) to do it ? Or do I have to manually create these lambdas in every region ?

Comment: No, there is not a simple way to do this via the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for this will be to use a [stack set in CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html).

> AWS CloudFormation StackSets extends the functionality of stacks by
> enabling you to create, update, or delete stacks across multiple
> accounts and regions with a single operation. Using an administrator
> account, you define and manage an AWS CloudFormation template, and use
> the template as the basis for provisioning stacks into selected target
> accounts across specified regions.

With a stack set, you can specify the accounts and regions to which you want to deploy your lambda.  You will likely want to put the lambda code in an S3 bucket that you can then reference from your CloudFormation template.

Then it is easy (and simple) to deploy to a new region--just add that region to the stack set.